# inserting product details into a 'product' table and product images in an 'image' table

Tags: php, mysql, image, insert, product

How can associate a product record in a table 'product' with its images in a different table 'images'?

**I am using auto-increment for product ids.**

I feel that it is not possible to do the association because the product id is auto-incremented hence not available during insert!

How can insert the new product, get product id then use it in the image table to relate product and images together?

Should I create a unique id my self instead of auto-incremented id?

**I am using PHP and MYSQL**

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
mysqli_insert_id()
```

It will get the last id inserted.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id

Answer (score 0):

Get the last inserted ID (in php).

Assuming you're using PDO: [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
$pid = $db->lastInsertId('your_id_column');
```

Or on mysqli: [Documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id)

```
mysqli_insert_id()
```